# How to give response in JSON for checked 1 or 0 for category from two different table?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables named `Category` and `user_category`

This is category table which contains all categories
[image: THIS IS CATEGORY TABLE WHICH CONTAINS ALL THE CATEGORY]

And this is the user_category table which contains the category selected by users[image: This is user_category table which contains the category selected by users]

Now I want to give response in JSON as if particular user want to update their category then earlier selected  category should be selected means 
in response checked 1

It is possible by PHP side or MySQL side? And how?

Like this:

```
{
"data":
    [
        {
            "cat_id": "1","category": "Drug","image_url": "1.jpg",
            "checked": "1"
        },{
            "cat_id": "2","category": "Bars","image_url": "2.jpg",
            "checked": "1"
        },
        {
            "cat_id": "3","category": "Bars","image_url": "2.jpg",
            "checked": "0"
        }, {
            "cat_id": "4","category": "Hair Saloon","image_url": "2.jpg",
            "checked": "0"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here as table data user has selected two categories (1 and 2) so in cat_id 1 and 2 `cheked='1'`; and which category is not selected then response `Checked='0';`

and here is my code

```
case 'cat':
            //$qry="SELECT cat_id,category,image_url FROM nesbaty_category";
            $qry="SELECT
                  nesbaty_category.cat_id,nesbaty_category.category, nesbaty_category.image_url, nesbaty_user_category.time
                  FROM nesbaty_category INNER JOIN nesbaty_user_category
                  ON nesbaty_category.cat_id = nesbaty_user_category.category            
                  WHERE nesbaty_user_category.user_id = '".$user_id."'";
            $qry_res=mysqli_query($con,$qry);
            $jsonData = array();
            while ($array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qry_res)) 
            {
                $jsonData['cat_id'] = $array['cat_id'];
                $jsonData['category'] = $array['category'];
                $jsonData['image_url'] = $array['image_url'];


                $response[] = $jsonData;
            }
            echo json_encode(array('data' =>$response));
            mysqli_close($con);
            break;
```

Comment: Post the code which you have tried.

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. 
You are expected to try to write the code yourself.
Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @pradeep patel check the question again a i have updated code

Answer (score 0):

You should get results of both of the tables in two different PHP variables.

1st variable would be having all the `Categories` from the main table

lets say `$all_categories`. This will be an array of all Categories.

2nd variable would be having all rows from `user_category` table for one particular use.

Then in your view, loop through all the categories with a `foreach` loop for 1at variable and create checkboxes inside the loop.
In the loop you can also check using `in_array` function if the 2nd has is having each particular category of the 1st variable.

I hope this is enough to understand.

Comment: Actually there is not checkbox it's webservice

Answer (score 0):

### Note: This is not an exact solution, this just gives an example of the approach

You can use an SQL `INNER JOIN()` to `SELECT()` all of the information that the current user has selected.

```
SELECT
    Category.category, Category.image_url, User_category.time
    FROM Category INNER JOIN User_category
        ON Category.cat_id = User_category.user_cat_id
            WHERE User_category.user_id = ?
```

You can then use the `json_encode()` and `header('Content-Type: application/json')` to return JSON formats to web requests.

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$driver = new PDO();
$driver->prepare(SQL HERE);
$stmt = $driver->execute(array((int)$_GET['userid']));
die(json_encode($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)));
```

You can then use a JQuery `$.ajax()` request to `GET` the current selected categories.

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        data: { userId: USER_ID_HERE },
        cache: false,
        url: URL_TO_ABOVE_PHP_HERE,

        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response); // Do what you want with data
        }
    });
});
```

Once you have shown the user the current categories he has selected, you can do the same vice versa (which I'll let you at least have a go at) and `POST` the data back to another PHP file, or a controller which handles both, which will run the `UPDATE()` SQL or `INSERT()`/`DELETE()` depending on your solution. You can use the JQuery `.change()` function to add listeners to your select boxes.

**[Here is a start to your solution you could look at over at JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/52vgfn4e/).**

Comment: This is return only selected category
but i want to display all the category from category table

Comment: Then update your SQL to fit relevantly, ie: `SELECT * FROM Category` and remove the `userId` field in the request and bind

Comment: you r right but also 
want response as checked 1 (if already selected)
and Checked 0 (if not selected)

Comment: `SELECT c.* ,
       (CASE WHEN uc.user_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as 'selected'
FROM nesbaty_category c LEFT JOIN
     nesbaty_user_category uc
     ON c.cat_id = uc.category AND uc.user_id = 1;`